# What is wrong with my square root code?

Tags: c

What is wrong with this code? I am learning both Python and C at the same time. Similar code on Python works fine but I am confused why this does not work here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float a, b, c,min_value, max_value;

int main(){
    printf("Enter a number here:");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    b=(max_value+min_value)/2;
    while(abs(b*b-a)>0.1){
        if (b*b>a){
            max_value=b;
            b=(max_value+min_value)/2;
        }
        else if(b*b<a){
            min_value=a;
            b=(max_value+min_value)/2;
        }
        printf("the square root of the number is %f",b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close because of debugging help.

Comment: “it doesn't work” is not an error description. What did you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: You need to initialize *min_value* and *max_value* to something (other than zero).

Answer (score 1):

In C, `abs` is an integer function - passing `float` values to it will result in truncation, so small values < +/-1.0 will just become 0. You need to use `fabs` for floating point values. Change:

```
while(abs(b*b-a)>0.1){
```

to:

```
while(fabs(b*b-a)>0.1){
```

and add:

```
#include <math.h>
```

near the top of your source file.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are wrong:

```
float a, b, c,min_value, max_value;
```

You shouldn't declare these variables outside the main function.

```
b=(max_value+min_value)/2;
```

`max_value` and `min_value` are not defined, what are you expecting here?

```
if (b*b>a){
    max_value=b;
    b=(max_value+min_value)/2;
}
else if(b*b<a){
        min_value=a;
        b=(max_value+min_value)/2;

}
```

Once again, `max_value` and `min_value` may not be defined. I could continue.

If you are trying to implement a `sqrt` function, perhaps you should take a look at someone else's code, as it seems obvious you lack knowledge in C.

Comment: OP also needs to include the corresponding header files.

Comment: global are initialized to 0, so min_value and max_value are initialized. And I agree,  this vars should not be global

Answer (score 0):

For future references, please state what your program is trying to accomplish and what errors are occuring.  Not trying to be mean or condescending; just giving you a heads up on Stack Overflow policy on question phrasing.

That said, on a brief glance I did notice that you also did not define "max_value" or "min_value" before using them in line 6 (where you set a value to "b").  In addition, declaring your variables outside the main function makes them global variables, which I would suggest avoiding if your variables are not going to be used in another program (via "#include ").

Comment: Disagree with "...  not define "max_value" or "min_value" before using them ..."  The are defined in code with `float a, b, c,min_value, max_value;`.  As global variables, they are initialized when the program runs.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch.  And if I recall they do have initialized values of NULL.

Comment: I think they are initialized with the bit pattern of zeros.  On most machines that is `0.0f` for a `float`.  I would use `min_value = 0.0; max_value = FLT_MAX;"`